# website does not run in IIS 10 on Windows 10 machine

Tags: iis

I've seen a couple of posts that are similar to this but I haven't been able to find any answers for my problem.

I'm just trying to set up a website in IIS. I'm on a Windows 10 machine and when I bring up the "About Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager" it says that the version is 10.0.1.7763.1. I know IIS is working because if I type `localhost` in my browser url address bar I get the default webpage that says IIS is running. I created a simple file called `index.html` that just says "hello there" in it. When I double click on this file my default browser opens up and displays "hello there" so I know that this file works in my browser.

Here's the steps I'm going through to create the website in IIS:

1. Right click on "Sites" in the connections pane.
2. Click "Add Website"
3. In "Site name:" box enter "BlahBlahWebsite.com"
4. In "Physical path:" box enter physical path to index.html
5. In "Host name:" box enter "BlahBlahWebsite.com"
6. Click "OK"

Here's what it looks like before I click "OK":

[screenshot of website configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQJN7.png)

Now from what I understand in IIS Manager I should be able to click the link under "Browse Website" in the "Actions" pane on the right side of IIS Manager but when I click the link that says "Browse BlahBlahWebsite.com on *:80(http)" instead of bringing up the index.html it takes me to the results of a search engine out on the internet. Am I understanding this wrong? How do I set it up so that I can browse to the index.html in my "BlahBlahWebsite" directory? Should I be entering something different in the url address bar? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: "Now from what I understand in IIS Manager I should be able to click the link" Nope. That's not correct. A binding means much more than you already knew, for example, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background Run the report and it can tell you more details.

Comment: @LexLi thanks for pointing out what the issue was. I tried to solve my issue using the link you listed but was not able to. However, after some searching I did find a solution to my issue. I submitted my own answer that outlines what I did to fix it. I tried to give you a +1 for your comment but my reputation is too low for me to be able to do so. Thank you very much for your insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @LexLi for putting me on the right path. I found [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8d44fb/how-to-access-the-site-using-domain-name-instead-of-localhos/) article that talks about configuring the localhost settings in the hosts file. I put an entry in my hosts file like this:

```
127.0.0.1    BlahBlahWebSite.com
```

and saved the hosts file. I could then enter `BlahBlahWebSite.com` in my browser url address bar or click on the `Browse BlahBlahWebsite.com on *:80(http)` link in IIS manager and both actions brought up my `index.html` page.

Another thing to note is that by editing your hosts file like this allows you to set up multiple websites, you just set up a new website as I listed above and then make a new entry in your hosts file. So, if I wanted to create a new website named `DifferentWebSite.com` in addition to `BlahBlahWebSite.com` I would go through the steps I outlined above to create `DifferentWebSite.com` in IIS Manager and then edit my hosts file so it would look like this:

```
 127.0.0.1    BlahBlahWebSite.com
 127.0.0.1    DifferentWebSite.com
```

and now I can enter either `BlahBlahWebSite.com` or `DifferentWebSite.com` in my browser url address bar or click the "Browse Website" link in the Actions pane in IIS and it will display my `index.html` page in the respective website directories.

Hope this helps anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the hosted site to application and then try to browse the site, this should solve your issue