# IIS website with windows authentication does not run on local Windows 10 machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, iis

I have a simple ASP.NET Core application that I want to run with IIS and Windows Authentication.

I tested and ran it before (before adding Windows Authentication and IIS) and it worked fine: It just opens a browser page and shows a json with names and birthday dates.

Now, I followed exactly the official [Microsoft Guide on how to Configure Windows Authentication in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) and after that worked, the [Microsoft Guide on how to "host ASP.NET Core on Windows with IIS"](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#browse-the-website). There I am stuck with the section

> Browse the website

Because when I try to access `http://www.iiswebsite.com/` (that's the name of the website I added by working through the above mentioned Guide), Chrome says "This site can't be reached".

I went through my configurations three times and made sure everything is set up correctly/as mentioned in the guide (please note: I use Windows desktop operating systems)

Here is something I don't understand: As suggested in the article about how to "[Configure Windows Authentication in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)", I added a `web.config` to the project's root with the required configuration. Here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <security>
        <authentication>
          <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
          <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
        </authentication>
      </security>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\FirstProject\FirstProject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\FirstProject.exe" arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="false" hostingModel="InProcess">
        <environmentVariables>
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
        </environmentVariables>
      </aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

But the [Microsoft Guide on how to "host ASP.NET Core on Windows with IIS"](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#browse-the-website) also suggests to add this line to `web.config`: `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">`. When I do so, it complains "The Project element is not declared". And when I publish, my website is still not found. Could this be the problem? Or am I doing something different totally wrong?

I hope the question is not too stupid. Normally I do Frontend stuff and ASP.NET Core, C#, IIS etc. is a whole new world to me.

I also searched StackOverflow with no success. Especially [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54622781/website-does-not-run-in-iis-10-on-windows-10-machine) looked helpful, but sadly it didn't work.

Additional information: The default IIS website on localhost runs successfully.

Comment: "But the Microsoft Guide on how to "host ASP.NET Core on Windows with IIS" also suggests to add this line to web.config: <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">" ? Read again because that's impossible.

Comment: About why Chrome cannot find that site, you probably messed up your DNS settings so requests do not even come to that IIS site. Surprised that a front end developer does not know enough of DNS, but once you search and learn something there, the cause is obvious.

Comment: Lex Li, sorry but your answer isn't helpful at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The domain `www.iiswebsite.com` is not a valid domain. It does not exist and Chrome does not know how to get to the domain.

**Solution (2 options)**

1. Use a valid domain that points to the IP of the server where your site is hosted.
2. Add a host entry for the domain `www.iiswebsite.com` in your computer's host file that points the the IP of the IIS server where your site is hosted

See this video that explains what DNS is: [DNS Explained](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=72snZctFFtA&feature=youtu.be&t=45)

For information on how to add a host entry see: [How to modify your hosts file in Windows 10](https://www.onmsft.com/how-to/how-to-modify-your-hosts-file-in-windows-10-and-why-you-might-want-to)

Comment: This did it for me! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

open your folder that project is in it using windows powershell, then write this is Powershell.

```
dotnet run
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! When I try this, it says: `The launch profile "(Default)" could not be applied.
A usable launch profile could not be located.`